# Which data mining or machine learning algorithm would be appropriate for learning ordered frequent patterns?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, association-rules

I have a dataset as `(var1, var2, out)`, where the ordered pair `<var1, var2>` gives `out`. Most of the frequent pattern mining algorithms like the Apriori and FP growth algorithms do not preserve the order of `var1` and `var2`.

Which are some of the available pattern mining algorithms (maybe also a NN trick), to find association rules between ordered pair `<var1, var2>` and output variable `out`?

Comment: What about KNN?

Comment: Can you please describe more on the suggested approach? As it is a big data problem, not sure what would be a reasonable value for k in KNN.

Comment: Maybe KNN is not the best choice if you deal with Big Data. What is the distributions of your features and outcomes?

Comment: in general pattern analysis is done with Markov models and also based on data, industry also algorithm changes

Comment: Can you give us more information? You have only two input variables? Or the variables are sets? The outcome is discrete?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have these two features (var1,  var2), you might want to:
 * Create one-hot encoded features for each variable under each position.
 * Add a column on which variable is first (e.g. two columns - likely to work with trees but not with anything else).
 * Take each possible combination of variables and use that as your only input (e.g. you then take the average of `out` for that combination, perhaps adding some prior or smoothing).

As the comments mentioned, if `out` is some discrete event, maybe you'd want to instead look at Markov models.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence mining seems the thing you are looking for. Used quite extensively in problems with ordered data, e.g. mapping DNA sequence -> disease. There are algorithms like SPADE and PrefixSpan.